# What is the difference between $L_1+L_2$ and $L_1 \cdot L_2$ in spin-spin coupling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, interactions

Consider two spin systems $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$, each with spin operator $L_1$ and $L_2$, respectively.

**What is the difference between $L_1+L_2$ and $L_1 \cdot L_2$?**

As far as I understand, both act component-wise on the tensor product space $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ so shouldn't they really be the same?

Comment: $L=L_1+L_2$ is diagonal in the product basis, i.e., it describes no coupling - just the total angular momentum. On the other hand, $L_1\cdot L_2$ is a true coupling. In general, a rule-of-thumb for two operators to be *the same*, is to have the same matrix representation - this is clearly not the case here.

Comment: @RogerVadim But isn't $(L_1\cdot L_2)h_1\otimes h_2=L_1h_1\otimes L_2h_2$ for all $h_i\in\mathcal{H}_i\,i=1,2$? That is basically the source of my confusion.

Comment: I suggest doing an exercise with two spins 1/2. The product basis is just four states and all the math is easily explicitly done on a page.

Comment: But what is the definition of $L_1\cdot L_2$? That's what I was referring to

Comment: Usually it is a scalar product of two operators (since angular momentum is a vector). But you have to check what it means in your context. If $+$ and $\cdot$ are not vector operatoions in your case, you would need to clarify the question.

Comment: You might be interested [in this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/651484/on-addition-of-angular-momenta-and-inner-product/651490#651490).

Comment: @Jakob Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for